# Deafult value loading for HTML.DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.title, (SelectList)ViewBag.NoVList, new { id = "natureOfVisit", @class = "text white" })
```

How can I add a deafult value to this DropDownListFor. I mean when the user will open the pop-up for editing a model where is this dropdown, to be selected the current model.title value from the dropdownbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set default value for dropdown, you should create appropriate SelectList:

```
ViewBag.NoVList = new SelectList(novs, "valueField", "textField", 1);
```

novs[1] will be default selection here.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.title, (SelectList)ViewBag.NoVList, "Please Select...", new { id = "natureOfVisit", @class = "text white" })
```

The third parameter is `optionLabel`.